# Changing UIActivityIndicator's color while animating

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

Is it possible to change the color of UIActivityIndicatorView while it is still animating? if anyone have had this issue, then you can suggest me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one Beautiful Link for you :
[ActivityIndicators](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=indicator)

I think you should try : [Custom Activity Indicator](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=336#more-336).

You can change the [UIActivityIndicatorStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) from any of these :

> UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge,
>   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite,
>   UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray,

Hope It helps !!!

Comment: Thats cool man, but actually what I need is to change the color of the default UIActivityIndicator. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 7):

I just tried the following code in a view controller class, and it worked on iOS 5+

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    _activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [_activityIndicator setCenter:self.view.center];

    [self.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(changeColor) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)changeColor
{
    _activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
}

@end
```

Comment: Brilliant! I tried everything, nothing affected the visible color until I tried the delayed set. I'm going to see if I can just dispatch to the main queue to get a tiny bit of delay, but wow - now there is hope!!! Not sure how you figured this out, but in any case its brilliant!

Answer (score 3):

```
refreshSpinner.color = [UIColor colorWithRed:X/255 green:Y/255 blue:Z/255 alpha:1.0];
```

Otherwise I think you are `init` the value twice

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 5.0 and up you can use setColor: on the `UIActivityIndicatorView` to set a custom color.

Like

```
Activity.color = [UIColor redColor];
```

**EDIT** :-

Try this

```
[activityIndicator setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can do this in a webview.Add a 'gif' image according to your View.**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *html2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body leftmargin=\"0\"     topmargin=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" marginheight=\"0\"><img id=\"img\" src=\"%@\" alt=\"\"  width=\"32\" height=\"32\" ></body><html>",@"loader.gif"];
    [self.web_Loader loadHTMLString:html2 baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if([ind isAnimating])
        {
            [ind setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
```